# moving colorbar with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am making a plot with multiple figures and corresponding colorbars. This page http://www.sc.eso.org/~bdias/pycoffee/codes/20160407/gridspec_demo.html claims to know the best way of doing so. I am inclined to believe them.
However, I have run into issues adressing the kwags of the colorbar when I do it their way:

```
from matplotlib.colorbar import Colorbar
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
median = np.zeros((100,100))
map0 = np.zeros((100,100))
map1 =  map0
map2 =  map0

fig = plt.figure()
plt.tight_layout()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,6)

ax  = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
cbax = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,2])
cbax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,3])

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,4])
cbax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,5])

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
cbax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1,1])

ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1,2])
cbax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1,3])

ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[1,4])
cbax5 = plt.subplot(gs[1,5])

cax = ax.imshow(map0)
ax.contour(median)
cb = Colorbar(ax = cbax,mappable = cax,shrink=0.8)

cax1 = ax1.imshow(map1)
ax1.contour(median)
cb1 = Colorbar(ax = cbax1,mappable = cax1)

cax2 = ax2.imshow(map2)
ax2.contour(median)
cb2 = Colorbar(ax = cbax2,mappable = cax2)

cax3 = ax3.imshow(map0/median)
ax3.contour(median)
cb3 = Colorbar(ax = cbax3,mappable = cax3)

cax4 = ax4.imshow(map1/median)
ax4.contour(median)
cb4 = Colorbar(ax = cbax4,mappable = cax4)

cax5 = ax5.imshow(map2)
ax5.contour(median)
cb5 = Colorbar(ax = cbax5,mappable = cax5)
```

When I now call the kwargs `shrink` and or `pad` I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_integratedMaps.py", line 173, in <module>
    main()
  File "plot_integratedMaps.py", line 171, in main
    plot_integratedMaps(map630,map869,mapTot,median)
  File "plot_integratedMaps.py", line 129, in plot_integratedMaps
    cb = Colorbar(ax = cbax,mappable = cax,shrink=0.8)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 943, in __init__
    ColorbarBase.__init__(self, ax, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shrink'
```

I guess it makes sense that I cant pad the colorbar in in the `gs[0,1]` and have to move`gs[0,1]` instead. But I don't get why shrink doesn't work?

am using `Python 2.7.12`

Comment: A sidenote: Never believe tutorials that claim to have found "the best way" of something. That is surely never true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not consider it useful to create `Colorbar` directly like in the link; instead one could use `fig.colorbar()`. However, this is only tangential to the problem.

First consider creating a colorbar next to a plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

median = np.zeros((100,100))
map0 = np.zeros((100,100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(map0)
ax.contour(median)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.8)

plt.show()
```

Here, `shrink` works fine because you want the axes in which the colorbar resides to be a factor 0.8 smaller than the axes `ax` to which it belongs.

Now, if you specify the axes in which the colorbar should reside, `shrink` does not make any sense, because the axes does not need to be created inside the colorbar function, but you supply it externally.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

median = np.zeros((100,100))
map0 = np.zeros((100,100))

fig, (ax,cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

im = ax.imshow(map0)
ax.contour(median)

#using `shrink` here would produce an error, 
# because the colorbar axes (cax) already exists
# instead of 
# cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, shrink=0.8)
# you need
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

Note that this is independend of gridspec. Whether or not you want to use gridspec is also a question of taste, but surely not needed for simple plots.

If you have more plots, it again depends what you want to show. The edited example from the question looks more like a regular grid. Here creating a colorbar axes for each subplot could be efficiently done via `make_axes_locatable`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(6,6)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    im = ax.imshow(data)
    div = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = div.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Taking the above, you may shrink the colorbars by not using this axes divider, but as usual, create your colorbar and use the `shrink` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(6,6)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    im = ax.imshow(data)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.4)

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `Note that this is independend of gridspec.`  Sorry, I dont get how this would be done with gridspec (My plot is complicated (i.e. 3*3 or 3*9 with colorbars), that's why I thought using gridspec made sense). 
Anyways I guess Im going to give up and just do it with a subplot....

Comment: Your question has a single subplot and it asked about the shrink argument. Of course if you have a larger grid, gridspec may make sense. If you want to edit your question with the actual problem you have (which is apparently not the shrink argument) I'm happy to edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem now, given that I explained why you cannot use the shrink argument?

Comment: I've edited the question. On a side note - I now got it to work with subplots. Am still interested how it is done with gridspec, since I do see their argument 
**gain:
total control over the plot
accuracy
elegance**

Comment: The question would be how I did, what I just did with subplot, with gridspec ?

Comment: What is "how I did"? The code from the question uses gridspec, right? So what is the problem? (Maybe step back a bit, reread your question and see if it is asking for what you want to know.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write, what you did. 
Essentially I want to move around the colorbar  (i.e. `shrink` or `pad`) using the gridspec grid. In the configuration I posted I would not be able to shrink only the colorbars when I use the `height_ratios` kwarg of `gridspec`. 
I think i should use `gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1,2)` to achieve that?

Comment: Probably you can use `gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec`, yes. For the case in the question however I would suggest to use an axes divider. I updated the answer.